# problems with including dependencies in package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why is it that when including dependencies in package.json such as

```
"dependencies": {
    "nodemailer": "*"
 }
```

and running

```
npm install
```

doesn't install the package but doing

```
npm install nodemailer
```

is ok?

in both instances, the message returned was

```
WARN Invalid name: "try node mailer"
WARN email No description
WARN email No repository field
WARN email No README field
WARN email No license field
```

but only in the second instance the node_modules directory is populated with the package

Comment: do you get any error in console after you run `npm install` with asterix?

Comment: ok have edited the post with the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest that you use some of the other version matching ranges and avoid the asterix one,, as per specs @page: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies

I did it fine with this one:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "my test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemailer": "~2"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

hope that helps you

Comment: thanks for the info ..hmm tried this but it still doesn't populate the node_modules directory with the nodeemailer package

Comment: try to compare your package or use mine,, it should work fine, I've checked and it's ok

Comment: thanks ! ive tried changing the "name" field in package.json and it works.

Comment: the name field was initially called "try node mailer" which apparently is an invalid package name

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a wildcard, you can try `""` instead. Otherwise this seems to be working:

```
{
  "name": "testr",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemailer": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```